# Installing SharePoint 2010 Foundation problem?

Tags: error

I'm having a problem with SharePoint 2010 Foundation in German. I've Windows Server 2008 R2 Enterprise Host and virtual machine with same system. In that virtual machine right after starting installer, progress bar shows up and error message is displayed 'fehler beim installieren dieses packets' which google translates to: 'error when installing this packets'. I am not german so hard to say if it's correct translation. The funny thing is I've downloaded english version of SharePoint 2010 Foundation and it shows up some gui (prerequisites) correctly, so there's clearly something wrong with that german version, and Google search says nothing about it. I've tried to use that German Sharepoint on 2ndary virtual server and it failed as well so it's not related to this particular VM (still it's same Host thou).

I've even downloaded that German version to my Win 7 x64 Enterprise and it started without problem so it doesn't seem like the package is broken on Microsoft servers.

Anyone got any ideas? Server is only 2nd Domain Controller with DNS and SQL Express R2 installed. Nothing else.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm a german IT consultant. Maybe I can help you at least by translating the German error messages. The Google translation is correct, the installer has some problem with the files included in the download.
Are there any more errors (e.g. inside the event logs)?
Did you try the file that you downloaded onto your Win7 machine? Maybe the version you have downloaded is corrupted?
Is your virtual server 64Bit?

Greetings from Germany,

Frank Piotrowsky

Comment: Hello Frank, I've downloaded this package 2 times, 1 times to other server and both had this problem. My colleague just downloaded this to his server and desktop (in different location) and has the same problem. But I've downloaded it to my desktop and I have no problems...  Yes VM's are 64bit.

Comment: I've copied .exe from my computer (the working one) and it works fine. Seems like some microsoft servers have bad version or so.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to install the file you've downloaded onto your Win7 machine on the server? Are there any more error messages (e.g. popup windows, event logs)?

By googling for the german error message I've found this one:
http://support.microsoft.com/?scid=kb;en-us;943589&x=8&y=14

It's not exactly for Sharepoint 2010 but Sharepoint 3.0. And it's just a hunch, because the error message itself does not provide sufficient information.

Comment: Btw I think you should respond within one Answer. This is Question and Answer site ;-) Not a normal forum.